# Unable to view form in designer view visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms

net programming . I created a form and add few controls in it. I close it then when I reopen it. Designer view was blank , was unable to add more controls in it. Have a look at this picture

[image]

Here is the code

[image]

Any help !

Comment: The second image you posted won't help us. Post the designer code.

Comment: Thank you I recreate whole project :)

Comment: I think there is an error on your source code, the image is not clear on the error! fix the error the designer will work pal.

Answer (score -1):

Try to exclude the form (all 3 files .vb, Designer.vb, .resx) and include it again into your project.